# How to use other file data in google app script by exporting

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, ecmascript-6

I am a react developer. I know how to export JSON data to another file. I am new to google appscript. I want to use **JSON data** in my google app script which is defined in **another file**. I know this process in react but not in google app script.

can anyone have a idea about it?

or

Is there any way to share the data to file.

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65508282/12511801).

Comment: if you json data is valid then use JSON parse method.  It returns an object.  If you don't know how to use an object the start [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

Comment: Where are you getting this file from?

Comment: I have created a .gs file for json data.

Comment: If you declare the json data as valid Javascript (for example as a `const somejson = { ... }` you can just call the constant from any other .gs file. All the .gs files share the same scope and you don't need to explicitly call them. Are you looking to use this .gs as some kind of properties file?